# Can't assign a specific class name to a collection of div's using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, coordinates

Hi ) I have a task and have done only a half of it, need some help:

1. need to make a board of 10/10 div's;
2. need to assign to each div a common class "box" and a specific one "box-x-y", where x and y are coordinates of the div;

I can't do the second task (the last half), for example for first div the class should be "box-1-1", and so on, like in the picture I have attached. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9iO8.png)

```js
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
          $("<div></div>").addClass("box").appendTo("#carousel");
      }
      $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo("#carousel");
  }
```

```css
.box {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="carousel">

  </div>
```

Comment: Did you tried this `addClass("box"+i+j)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have already done the hardwork, create the class using string concatenation and then use `addClass()` method.

```
var cls = 'box-' + (i+1) + '-' + (j+1);
$("<div></div>").addClass("box").addClass(cls).appendTo("#carousel");
```

Note: I have used `text()` for demo

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var cls = 'box-' + (i+1) + '-' + (j+1);
    $("<div></div>").addClass("box").addClass(cls).text(cls).appendTo("#carousel");
  }
  $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo("#carousel");
}
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
          $("<div></div>").addClass("box").addClass("box-"+(i+1)+"-"+(j+1)).appendTo("#carousel");
      }
      $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo("#carousel");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){

          var classes = "box "+"box-"+i+"-"+j;
          $("<div></div>").addClass(classes).appendTo("#carousel");
      }
      $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo("#carousel");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comment you can do that by adding for loop variable in the addclass function `addClass("box box-"+i+"-"+j)`. Now we are adding two classes into div `.box` and .`box-dynamic-number`, the first one while apply the css on the div and second is your requirement.

```js
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
       
          $("<div>box-"+i+"-"+j+"</div>").addClass("box box-"+i+"-"+j).appendTo("#carousel");
      }
      $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo("#carousel");
  }
```

```css
.box {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="carousel">

  </div>
```